# Azure Virtual Machine LinuxDiagnostic Extension OMI EnumerateInstances failed (Linux Diagnostic OMI)

Tags: azure, logging, azure-virtual-machine, azure-log-analytics

I have the Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.LinuxDiagnostic extension installed on a Linux VM. The status is provisioned but I am seeing the following error. Also, I can see many instances of this process spawning on the VM but not ending.

Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.LinuxDiagnostic 3.0.125

```
message in mdsd.err:2019-11-24 20:45:54:teInstances failed 2019-11-24T20:42:51.6977410Z:
Error: OMI EnumerateInstances failed 2019-11-24T20:42:52.5613990Z:
Error: OMI EnumerateInstances failed 2019-11-24T20:42:52.6530490Z:
Error: OMI EnumerateInstances failed 2019-11-24T20:42:54.1041570Z:
Error: OMI EnumerateInstances failed 2019-11-24T20:42:54.1293820Z:
Error: OMI EnumerateInstances failed 2019-11-24T20:44:21.7000600Z:
Error: OMI EnumerateInstances failed 2019-11-24T20:44:22.5628890Z:
Error: OMI EnumerateInstances failed 2019-11-24T20:44:22.6550040Z:
Error: OMI EnumerateInstances failed 2019-11-24T20:44:24.1062670Z:
Error: OMI EnumerateInstances failed
```

Any ideas about how to resolve this? If I uninstall the extension, does the VM need to be rebooted? I presume I'll no longer see log analytics if uninstalled?

Comment: It doesnt need to be rebooted, but it might help rebooting the vm to stop all the processes that might be working that prevent the proper reinstall of the agent. are you using the latest version for the extension? you can set `autoupgrademinorversion` to true on the extension properties to get the latest version. that might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your reply.

I decided to uninstall the extension, reboot the VMs, install the latest extension again and reboot. This was successful.

Comment: For anyone who doesn't find this obvious, you uninstall the extension by going to the VM in the Azure Portal, select 'Extensions' in the left-hand menu and then click the 3 dots menu on the right-hand side and click 'Uninstall'